# antd DatePicker: Disable minutes only for given hour

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, antd

I am using [DatePicker](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#components-date-picker-demo-time) from antd.

```
<LocaleProvider locale={enUS}>
    <DatePicker
      format="MM/D/YYYY HH:mm"
      defaultValue={this.getStartValue()}
      showTime={{format: 'HH:mm'}}
      placeholder="Start"
      allowClear={false}
      onOk={this.onStartTimeChange}
    />
</LocaleProvider>
<LocaleProvider locale={enUS}>
    <DatePicker
      format="MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm"
      defaultValue={this.getEndValue()}
      showTime={{format: 'HH:mm'}}
      placeholder="End"
      allowClear={false}
      onOk={this.onEndTimeChange}
    />
</LocaleProvider>
```

Requirement here is:

- For startDate, dates beyond end date should be disabled, also time beyond end time should be disabled.

I have achieved disabling date using disabledDate.

Now for time I am trying using disabledTime props but am unable to understand on how to disable minutes only for given hour

For example
If end time: 18:34
Then all time from 00:00  to 18:33 should be enabled and all times from 18:34 - 23:59 should be disabled.

==============================

```
getDateTime(value) {
    const dateTime = {};
    dateTime.date = value.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    dateTime.hour = value.hour();
    dateTime.minute = value.minute();
    return dateTime;
}

getDisplayTime(dateTime) {
    const date = dateTime.date;
    const hour = dateTime.hour;
    const minute = dateTime.minute;
    const timeStr = `${date} ${hour}:${minute}`;
    return moment(timeStr, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm');
}

onStartTimeChange(value) {
    if (value) {
        this.props.updateStartTime(this.getDateTime(value));
    }
}

onEndTimeChange(value) {
    if (value) {
        this.props.updateEndTime(this.getDateTime(value));
    }
}

getStartValue() {
    return this.getDisplayTime(this.props.startTime);
}

getEndValue() {
    return this.getDisplayTime(this.props.endTime);
}

disabledStartDate(current) {
    // Can not select days after end date
    const endDate = this.getEndValue();
    return current && endDate && current.valueOf() > endDate.valueOf();
}

range(start, end) {
    const result = [];
    for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
        result.push(i);
    }
    return result;
}

disabledStartDateTime(current) {
    const endDate = this.getEndValue();
    if (current && endDate && current.valueOf() !== endDate.valueOf()) {
        return {};
    }
    const hour = current.hour();
    const minute = current.minute();
    return {
        disabledHours: () => {
            if (hour < 23) {
                let start = hour;
                if (minute !== 0) {
                    start += 1;
                }
                return this.range(start, 24);
            }
            return [];
        },
        disabledMinutes: () => {
            if (current.hour() === hour) {
                return this.range(minute, 60);
            }
            return [];
        }
    };
}

<LocaleProvider locale={enUS}>
    <DatePicker
      format='MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm'
      defaultValue={this.getStartValue()}
      showTime={{format: 'HH:mm'}}
      allowClear={false}
      showToday={false}
      disabledDate={this.disabledStartDate}
      disabledTime={this.disabledFromDateTime}
      hideDisabledOptions={true}
      onChange={this.onStartTimeChange}
    />
</LocaleProvider>

<LocaleProvider locale={enUS}>
    <DatePicker
      format='MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm'
      defaultValue={this.getEndValue()}
      showTime={{format: 'HH:mm'}}
      allowClear={false}
      showToday={false}
      hideDisabledOptions={true}
      onChange={this.onEndTimeChange}
    />
</LocaleProvider>
```

==============================

Answer (score 0):

`<DatePicker ... showTime={{ format: "...", disabledMinutes: this.disabledMinutes}} />`

And then

```
disabledMinutes = ( hour ) => {
    let minutes = []
    // Check which minutes 0..59 should be disabled during this hour
    // and push each minute to the minutes array. 
    return minutes
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. basically ok button is coming disabled but am using on change and these values are shown as selectable (and onChange is triggered) as soon as user click anywhere in time. I need on change so that I can handle case where user manually edit input field.

Comment: Show your code, otherwise it is hard to help further. What I posted above has nothing to do with any OK button.

Comment: Sorry, I gave you the answer using `TimePicker`. When you use `TimePicker` embedded inside a `DatePicker` you need to pass the options in the `showTime={...}` argument. Answer updated.